# Bash character ! of special history command

Tags: bash, history

How do we change bash character ! for special history command to other direct single key character such as `=` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [the `histchars` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-histchars):

> Up to three characters which control history expansion, quick
> substitution, and tokenization (see [History Interaction](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction)). The
> first character is the
> *history expansion* character, that is, the character which signifies the start of a history expansion, normally '`!`'. The second character
> is the character which signifies 'quick substitution' when seen as the
> first character on a line, normally '`^`'. The optional third
> character is the character which indicates that the remainder of the
> line is a comment when found as the first character of a word, usually
> '`#`'. The history comment character causes history substitution to be
> skipped for the remaining words on the line. It does not necessarily
> cause the shell parser to treat the rest of the line as a comment.

So:

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ histchars='=^'
$ =echo
echo foo
foo
$
```

But: there are occasional assumptions in the code that `!` is the history expansion character (mostly for setting exceptions, like in globbing). Setting it to `=` will break a lot of things, like setting variables:

```
$ a=e
aecho foo
bash: aecho: command not found
$ a'='e
bash: a=e: command not found
$ a\=e
bash: a=e: command not found
$ printf -v a e
$ echo $a
e
```